# How can register yahoo web analytics?

Tags: yahoo

i can't find from url: `http://web.analytics.yahoo.com/`

at : `flurry.com` only can register Android app, iOS app.

How can register yahoo web analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service [has been discontinued](http://marketingland.com/yahoo-web-analytics-to-be-discontinued-14223). You can't sign up for it, it no longer exists.

Comment: it has been discontinued from 2012? oh, my god.